# Modular approach for chatbot services plugins

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not just talking about plugins and plugin loaders.
Suppose there's a main python script which handles all chatbot logic.
I want to be able to attach multiple channels (services) like telegram and slack to it.
Right now, it (delicately) works with imports (both import each other). But this cannot scale for multiple services. Each service calls a function of the main script and the main script calls a function in the service script to reply.

Is there any way for modules / imported classes to communicate with the parent?

Comment: Your description is quite general, but usually this kind of problem is solved with Inheritance. You make a general `class chatbot:` and the different plugins you mention import this class and inherit it: `class slackChatbot(chatbot):`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a great idea to separate logic and communication layer. I've found https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Wizard but not sure if it is usable.

As for me I solved this problem implementing logic at flask server and creating "dumb" bots which proxied user messages to flask. It is great pain in ass if you want to use some channel-specific features (like geo in Telegram)